# Suggestions do not appear

Tags: magento, algolia

I installed the module "algolia" in my magento store however the products do not appear as suggestions when performing a search.
The module already installed and configured correctly and even folders already has read written permission.

Every time I start typing a word in the search box my Algolia control panel shows the error 403 (forbidden) for the POST request, I need to configure any permission in my database?

Comment: There's a lot of things that could have gone wrong here. We have no way of helping you without you sharing any code.

Comment: There is not modified code, the module has a fixed code and magento too.
I would like to know is if there is any extra configuration to be made for the module to work

Comment: 403 probably means you have the wrong credentials. Have you double checked?

Comment: Are you using a custom package/theme? Also, what version of Algolia and Magento are you using?